# Relation between independent and dominating set

Tags: graph-theory, intuition

I came across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Independent_domination) paragraph on wikipedia page:

> Dominating sets are closely related to independent sets: an independent set is also a dominating set if and only if it is a maximal independent set, so any maximal independent set in a graph is necessarily also a minimal dominating set. Thus, the smallest maximal independent set is greater or equal in size than the smallest independent dominating set. The independent domination number $i(G)$ of a graph $G$ is the size of the smallest independent dominating set (or, equivalently, the size of the smallest maximal independent set).
>   The minimum dominating set in a graph will not necessarily be independent, but the size of a minimum dominating set is always less than or equal to the size of a minimum maximal independent set.

I didnt get following

1. **The Second sentence**: "Thus, the smallest maximal independent set is greater or equal in size than the smallest independent dominating set."
2. **The last half sentence**: "but the size of a minimum dominating set is always less than or equal to the size of a minimum maximal independent set"

Some facts:

1. Maximal independent set is also minimal dominating (as stated in first line in above paragraphs)
2. Independent dominating set is also maximal independent as specified [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_independent_set):

   > A set of vertices is a maximal independent set if and only if it is an independent dominating set.

Now my doubts:

1. I believe, due to point 1 and 2 above, we can say,

   > *Size of maximal independent set
   >
   >   = Size of minimal independent dominating set*

   Adding "smallest" on both sides above, we get

   > *Size of smallest maximal independent set
   >
   >   = Size of smallest minimal independent dominating set*

   Then the second sentence must be wrong in saying "greater or equal", right?
2. I understand that minimal dominating sets can be either independent or not-independent. Similarly smallest dominating sets can be either independent or non-independent. I believe in the last half sentence , wikipedia article meant "smallest" by "minimum" (right?). As stated in above point

   > *Size of smallest maximal independent set
   >
   >   = Size of smallest minimal independent dominating set*

   Adding to this the set of smallest non-independent dominating set makes set of smallest dominating set. Then how is the last half sentence correct in saying "less than or equal"? I guess it should be "greater than or equal", right?

PS: note that smallest set is by fact minimal, so we can very well drop "minimal" following "smallest" and add "minimal" after "smallest" as per convinience.

**Edit**
I guess, I got it. Need confirmation for below.
I was wrong in saying: "Adding to this the set of smallest non-independent dominating set makes set of smallest dominating set." Smallest dominating set is either smallest independent dominating set  or smallest non-independent dominating set, if both have different size. Thus smallest dominating set equals smallest independent dominating set if smallest independent dominating set is smaller than smallest non independent dominating set. Whereas, smallest dominating set is less than smallest independent dominating set if smallest independent dominating set is greater than smallest non independent dominating set, in which case smallest dominating set is equals smallest non independent dominating set.

Am I thinking unnecessarily too much?

Comment: When you juggle so many adjectives, it is difficult to keep them straight. First of all, "minimum" and "smallest" have no place here unless one proves that there only one minimal (...) set, in which case they would mean the same thing. However, for this case it is false. Now "smallest size" would have been correct, and appears to be what the author meant. Wherever it talks about  "size of smallest" or "size of minimum", it actually means "smallest size of a" or "minimum size of a".

Comment: **(1)** I feel `"minimum" and "smallest" have no place here unless one proves that there only one minimal (...) set` is incorrect. There can be multiple minimal dominating sets and single smallest dominating set, since minimal dominating set means set from which we cant remove any vertex while preserving its dominating nature. Each of minimal dominating sets can be of different size, or some (or all) of them may be of same size. The one with smallest size (if it happened to be the only one of this size) is smallest minimal dominating set. **(2)** didnt get `(...)` [continued..]

Comment: [..continued] **(3)** Didnt get `in which case they would mean the same thing. However, for this case it is false. Now "smallest size" would have been correct, and appears to be what the author meant.` In fact, I didnt get how you are distinguishing between minimum and smallest dominating set. Can you define them explicitly for clarity?

Comment: (1) I *didn't say* you could prove there was only one minimal set. In fact, I said just the opposite: "However, in this case it is false". My point is that the terms "minimum" and "smallest" are NOT justified here, exactly because there ISN"T a single minimal set. (2) the (...) is a place holder for whatever condition you are dealing with. In the text, they talk about minimal dominating sets and minimal independent dominating sets. My point applies to either condition or any other condition you can apply the term "minimal" to. "Minimum" means the unique minimal set having the condition.

Comment: And if there is no such unique set, then there is no "minimum" or "smallest". (3) I am NOT disquishing between those. However, I am distiguishing between "size of the smallest set of (whatever)" and "smallest size of a set of (whatever)". In the first sentence "smallest" applies to the sets, which requires a unique minimal set as I've just re-iterated. In the second, "smallest" applies to the *size* of the sets, and as these are just natural numbers, there is always a smallest. I'm pointing out that the author used "size of smallest" when they really meant "smallest size".